# Combine multiple rest api's into one front end with wso2

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a list of assignments containing setting up wso2, creating rest api, exporting the swagger file and now we have to combine our local rest api's (6 in total) to one front end application with a rather large amount of freedom in how the implementation will happen. We had a maximum time of 1 week but that has shrank now to 2 days. Is there something premade that will allow us to integrate our api's rather easily?

I've been trying to get it to work for my own application all day without a lot of succes using this guide: https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2019/08/building-a-react-based-single-page-application-to-consume-an-api-deployed-in-wso2-api-manager/

I am really not finding the proper steps on google so we can achieve this assignment or even start and hope someone else has done this task before and knows how to proceed.

Comment: Hi @pieterjan it seems your issue is with building a client/how to consume these API's and not with the API's or WSO2 itself?
Can you be more clear on what you have to achieve, which technologies you use, what you have done so far and what the problem is (specific error, strange result etc)? Currently the question is very broad and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

How about using API products in API Manager? Here you can combine multiple APIs and create a new super API with a common context and version. You can refer each operation in the API as a resource of this API Product. More info can be found here [1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api-product/api-product-overview/